# How to Split Street Address String and Replace Individual elements

Tags: c#

I need to take a street address, just the address line, `111 Stackoverflow Drive North` split the individual `strings` and `replace` specific elements.

For example: I need to replace elements in the string so that it looks like this:

*Input:* `111 Stackoverflow Drive North` *Output:* `111 Stackoverflow Dr N`
So basically, if the address line contains Av or Avenue then replace with `Ave`.

The only way I know how to do this is to use the `Replace Method` back to back.

Example:

```
 string input = "111 Stackoverflow Drive North";
 string address = input.ToLower().Replace("north", "N").Replace("drive", "Dr");
```

This looks pretty verbose: I was thinking about creating a list of values then split the address and replace but not sure how to put the two together.

Comment: Address normalization is a VERY tricky subject.  If you need to be USPS conform, don't try to write it yourself.  There is CASS certified software that does this perfectly (expensive), and a number of low-cost solutions that do it well.

Comment: Understood, I just need to do some formatting. I do not need to validate or verify the address.

Comment: What happens with "11 North Drive Avenue"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Address normalization is a VERY tricky subject. If you need to be USPS conform, don't try to write it yourself. There is CASS certified software that does this perfectly (expensive), and a number of low-cost solutions that do it well.

Having said that, you can tokenize the input string, and then concatenate the values together either by using the replacement if one is defined, otherwise by using the original value.

```
Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "DRIVE", "DR" }
};

string[] tokens = originalAddress.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' });
StringBuilder normalized = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string t in tokens)
{
    string rep;
    bool found = replacements.TryGetValue(t.ToUpper(), out rep);

    if (found)
    {
        normalized.Append(rep);
    }
    else
    {
        normalized.Append(t);
    }
    normalized.Append(' ');
}

// normalized.ToString() contains the normalized address
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use this codeplex project that tokenizes and parses address:

http://usaddress.codeplex.com/

Then you have access to the various pieces of information.

Comment: Had not seen that before.  Nice find.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Dictionary` for this

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"north", "N"}, {"drive", "Dr"}};

string address = string.Join(" ",
            input.Split().Select(x =>
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(x.ToLower())) 
                     return dict[x.ToLower()];

                return x;
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`StringBuilder.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a loop, for example with this method:

```
public static String ReplaceAll(string original, Dictionary<String, String> replacements)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(original);
    foreach (var kv in replacements)
    {
        sb.Replace(kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think or can I do this using a csv file with the stored values? Just a thought.

Comment: This iterates through `sb` once per replacement.  Probably not a real-life concern, but worth noting.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: of course, what problems do you expect? But if the number of replacement strings is large you should probably use a different approach.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I was just curious. So many great solutions and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the replace, but I would recommend, as others have, a dictionary with look ups and replacements inside of a loop. See below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> replacementDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
replacementDictionary.Add("north", "N");
replacementDictionary.Add("south", "S");
// Add more entries here
```

Then when you have an address with replacement in question, you can search your dictionary for a replacement entry:

```
string addressInQuestion = "101 north Almond drive";
string finalAddress;
foreach(string token in addressInQuestion.Split(' '))
{
    string replacementToken = token;
    replacementDictionary.TryGetValue(token, out replacementToken)
    finalAddress += replacementToken;
}
```

This will also avoid replacing possible unintended replacements of 'combined-token' words such as "101 Northbridge Way". Of course, you will have to write your capitalization and spacing rules yourself :)